# Can winds also arise due to a statistical probability that more air molecules suddenly gets an equal direction?

Tags: thermodynamics

Although air molecules have an average speed of about 1,500 km/h if there is no wind the air would stay still. The reason for that is that the directions of the molecules cancel each other out.

But is there a probability that wind arise because a majority of the molecules get the same direction? Or is this only theoretically possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a probability, but it is smaller than small. It would be so small that this would only be theoreticslly possible.
Think for a simple example of about a mol of pafticles (22 liter) but this is 6 e23 particles. For all of them to point kn the same half space(prob 1/2) the probability would be 2^(-6e23). Multplied by time inbetween collisions this number is still insanely small.

Of course this is not a refined example nor accurate but it shows a tendency.

Comment: if one takes into account conservation of momentum and angular momentum the probability will become even smaller.